# Kali linux run airbase-ng along with wpa_supplicant

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, bridge, wpa-supplicant, wifi-hotspot

I have a notebook with installed kali linux with a built-in wireless card and I have also an external USB wireless adapter. I'm able to connect to networks with both of them, and I have no problems when using airbase-ng to set up an AP with the built-in card. But what I wanted to do was to connect to my network (uses WPA) with the usb dongle, and share it's Internet access with the airbase AP. The problem is that airbase-ng doesn't want to work when wpa_supplicant is running, and without it, I just can't connect to WPA networks. If you know how to make this work, I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

```
airmon-ng check kill
ifconfig wlan0 up
wpa_passphrase "essid" "password" > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlan0
dhclient wlan0
```

This way you can connect through the terminal